error with getting cmv3 guards
I'm trying to write a script to get guards cmv3 based on an example from the documentation https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/guards , but I get errors
import {
  fetchCandyMachine,
  fetchCandyGuard,
  findCandyGuardPda,
  deserializeCandyMachine,
  deserializeCandyGuard,
  assertAccountExists,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine';
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';

async function getCandyMachineGuards(candyMachineAddress) {
  const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');
  const umi = { connection };

  const candyMachinePubkey = new PublicKey(candyMachineAddress);

  const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, candyMachinePubkey);
  const candyGuard = await fetchCandyGuard(umi, candyMachine.mintAuthority);

  console.log('Guards:', candyGuard.guards);
  console.log('Bot Tax:', candyGuard.guards.botTax);
  console.log('Sol Payment:', candyGuard.guards.solPayment);
}

const candyMachineAddress = 'HZBH6N6e7xoJB7CpMHiruecL38MJBHQMQcYLXKFsbky';
getCandyMachineGuards(candyMachineAddress);


What could be the mistake?

Can you check how you are initializing umi?
In the code you provided, umi is assigned the Connection object, which is wrong.
Your errors might be related to how you are initializing your umi instance.
Here is how I would go about it using the core candy machine.
Note that this shouldn't be any different from TM Candy machine, you'll just have to change the imports to @metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-core-candy-machine
import {
    isSome,
    keypairIdentity,
    publicKey as UMIPublicKey,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
    fetchCandyGuard,
    findCandyGuardPda,
    mplCandyMachine,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-core-candy-machine";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";

export const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const umi = createUmi(connection);

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from("UPDATE WITH SECRET KEY"));

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplCandyMachine());

async function getCandyGuards() {
    const candyMachineAddress = UMIPublicKey(
        "5HqK3wZxPkgajmWCM4gH3ibYdgh9mAvA6Adc9gcfwyh9"
    );

    const candyGuardAddress = findCandyGuardPda(umi, {
        base: candyMachineAddress,
    });

    const guards = (await fetchCandyGuard(umi, candyGuardAddress)).guards;
    const availableGuards = Object.values(guards).filter((guard) =>
        isSome(guard)
    );

    console.log(availableGuards);
}

getCandyGuards().then().catch(console.error);


updated the answer
